# Firefox "The page isn’t redirecting properly" for a Wiki (all other Pages and UAs are OK)

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, mediawiki, firefox

We are having trouble with a website for a free and open source project. The website and its three components are as follows. Its running on a CenOS 7 VM hosted by someone else (PaaS).

- site: www.cryptopp.com (apache)
- manual: www.cryptopp.com/docs (doxygen)
- wiki: www.cryptopp.com/wiki (mediawiki)

The Apache version is Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS). The PHP version is 5.4.16 (cli) (built: Aug 11 2016 21:24:59). The Mediawiki version is 1.26.4.

The main site is OK and can be reached through both cryptopp.com and www.cryptopp.com in all browsers and user agents. The manual is OK and can be reached through both cryptopp.com/docs and www.cryptopp.com/docs in all browsers and user agents.

The wiki is OK under most Browsers and all tools. Safari is OK. Internet Explorer is OK. Chrome is untested because I don't use it. Command line tools like cURL and wget are OK. A trace using wget is below.

The wiki is a problem under Firefox. It *cannot* be reached at either cryptopp.com/wiki and www.cryptopp.com/wiki in Firefox. Firefox displays an error on both OS X 10.8 and Windows 8. Firefox is fully patched to the platform. The failure is:

[image]

We know the problem is due to a recent change to direct all traffic to HTTPS. The relevant [addition to `httd.conf`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14482032/608639) is below. The change in our policy is due to [Chrome's upcoming policy change](https://www.wired.com/2016/11/googles-chrome-hackers-flip-webs-security-model/all/1#slide-1) regarding Security UX indicators.

I know these are crummy questions (none of us are webmasters or admins in our day job)... What is the problem? How do I troubleshoot it? How do I fix it?

---

***wget trace***

```
$ wget http://cryptopp.com/wiki/ 
--2016-11-05 12:53:54--  http://cryptopp.com/wiki/
Resolving cryptopp.com (cryptopp.com)... 192.210.150.121
Connecting to cryptopp.com (cryptopp.com)|192.210.150.121|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/ [following]
--2016-11-05 12:53:54--  https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/
Resolving www.cryptopp.com (www.cryptopp.com)... 192.210.150.121
Connecting to www.cryptopp.com (www.cryptopp.com)|192.210.150.121|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Main_Page [following]
--2016-11-05 12:53:54--  https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Main_Page
Connecting to cryptopp.com (cryptopp.com)|192.210.150.121|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘index.html’

index.html              [ <=>                ]  20.04K  --.-KB/s    in 0.03s   

2016-11-05 12:53:54 (767 KB/s) - ‘index.html’ saved [20520]
```

---

***Firefox access_log***

```
# tail -16 /var/log/httpd/access_log
<removed irrelevant entries>
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:52 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:52 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:53 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:53 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:53 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:53 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:53 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:53 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:53 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:54 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
71.244.244.203 - - [05/Nov/2016:13:00:54 -0400] "GET /wiki/Main_Page HTTP/1.1" 302 20 "https://www.cryptopp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:48.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/48.0"
```

---

***[`httd.conf` change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14482032/608639)***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.cryptopp.com
    ServerAlias *.cryptopp.com *.cryptopp.* cryptopp.com

    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
        RewriteRule .* - [F]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACK
        RewriteRule .* - [F]

        #redirect all port 80 traffic to 443
        RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
        RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.cryptopp.com/$1 [L,R]
    </IfModule>    
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.cryptopp.com
    ServerAlias *.cryptopp.com *.cryptopp.* cryptopp.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: What version of Firefox on what platform?  I can access your site fine with Firefox 49 Linux: `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0`

Comment: As for how to investigate, I use [Live HTTP Headers extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) to figure out what HTTP(S) requests are actually being made by Firefox in situations like this.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - Firefox 48.0.2 on OS X 10.8.5 and Firefox 49.0.2 on Windows 8.1. Are you certain you hit the wiki (trouble) and not the main site (OK)? Top menu bar with yellow background -> "Wiki and FAQ".

Comment: Yes, I started with `http://cryptopp.com/wiki/ ` which redirected to `https://cryptopp.com/wiki/` which redirected  to `https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Main_Page` which displayed fine.

Comment: Browsers (including Firefox) sometimes cache the fact that a URL redirects.  If you have changed your rewrite rules, make sure you clear the cache in the browser before re-testing.  (Although you wouldn't usually see evidence in your server log in that case.)

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - If this page is still correct: [How can I clear a single site from the cache in Firefox](http://superuser.com/q/173210), then it does not appear to be a cache problem. After deleting all history for the site, the problem still exists.

Comment: I don't get a redirect error but it does go to the wiki. I do not, however, see a yellow background Wiki and FAQ as you describe.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - You may be right... I opened a Private Browsing Session under Firefox and the site displayed properly.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - OK, it was a cache problem. I closed Firefox and deleted `~/Library/Caches/*` and the problem did not return. Do you feel like answering so I can accept?

Comment: This works OK for me too on Firefox 49.0.2 on Windows 7. As Stephen suggests, you'll need to check the network traffic the browser is seeing when you get this error. Minor point (not the cause of your problem)... your HTTP to HTTPS redirect should be a permanent (301) redirect, not a temporary (302) that you currently have. ie. change `R` to `R=301`. (Note that 301 redirects _will be_ cached by the browser.)

Comment: I feel this whole question should be closed cause it's just an error and a common one.

Comment: @Rob - Fair enough. I mildly disagree given the steps we performed and the testing we performed. I would be interested in knowing why it only affected the wiki portion of the site, and not the other two areas. But if you cast a close vote, then I will move to close also. Or maybe you can find a duplicate, and I will accept as a duplicate.

Comment: It should be closed because the problem does not appear if you refresh the page. This is an error in testing, not server configuration, browsers or anything else. The common response on stackoverflow and serverfault, where this question belongs, is "did you refresh your browser".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers (including Firefox) sometimes cache the fact that a URL redirects. If you have changed your rewrite rules, make sure you clear the cache in the browser before re-testing. (Although you wouldn't usually see evidence in your server log in that case.)

As for how to investigate, I use [Live HTTP Headers extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/) to figure out what HTTP(S) requests are actually being made by Firefox in situations like this.

I think in your case you may have had a 301 redirect configured at one point from `/wiki/Main_Page` to `/wiki/`.   Firefox got that permanent redirect into it's cache.   Then later when it got `/wiki/` it found that was a 302 redirect to `/wiki/Main_Page`.  302 temporary redirects are *not* cached, so it was doing:

1. Fetch from server `/wiki/`, 302 to `/wiki/Main_Page`
2. Fetch from cache `/wiki/Main_Page`, 301 to `/wiki/`
3. Fetch from server `/wiki/`, 302 to `/wiki/Main_Page`
4. Fetch from cache `/wiki/Main_Page`, 301 to `/wiki/`
5. Fetch from server `/wiki/`, 302 to `/wiki/Main_Page`
6. Fetch from cache `/wiki/Main_Page`, 301 to `/wiki/`
7. ...
8. Error, infinite redirect

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that was it. Would you happen to know why it only affected the wiki portion of the site? I guess that's the perplexing thing to me at the moment.

Comment: I added more to my answer about a plausible scenario that could have caused all the evidence that you put in your question.

Comment: Thanks again Stephen. Here's some more feedback for future travels... It looks like the rule broke MediaWiki. The rewrite rule that turned all HTTP into HTTPS broke MediaWiki's logon. When we click logon, the UTR clearly shows HTTPS in the address bar. And MediaWiki is clearly telling us to "login using a secure connection". MediaWiki sucks. Its an awful piece of software.